# iOS in-app purchases do not display (maybe bundle id issue?)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to use test code from another developer. I changed the bundle id of the project and setup all code signing identity and provision profiles. But still cannot see purchase data in app (price, description etc.). I think the issue is that I use my provision profiles with my bundle id. But purchases registered for another bundle id (of example, my bundle id is com.self.edu, purchases id is com.another.testapp.purchase1). So I must use only purchases only with correct bundle id (in example I must use bundle id something like com.another.testapp)?

Comment: Have you setup the IAP in iTunes Connect under your new bundle Id?

Comment: No. As I said: I trying to test purchases which create another developer (for another bundle id) with my provision profiles (so with my bundle id in target settings). I think I cannot do this, right? I can use in-app purchases with correct bundle id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the bundle Id for which the IAPs have been established on iTunes Connect.